# C - Passing uninitialised variables to array elements

Tags: c, arrays, loops, initialization

I'm wondering how do I handle uninitialised variables that I'm passing to another variable.

I am trying to write a program that at the end of it, after the user enters all the numbers, the highest and lowest numbers are shown.

```
int n[5], i, small, large;

for(i=0; i < 5; i++){

    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n[i]);

    if(n[i] >= large){
        large = n[i];
    }
    else if (n[i] <= small){
        small = n[i];
    }
```

This produces the correct output (states the smallest number) but for the largest number, a random number is produced.

How can this be dealt with, besides initalising large to 0 (which will render the program inaccurate when negative numbers are entered)?

Thanks.

Comment: Initialize both variables *unconditionally* with the **first** entered number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize `large` to a really small value, and `small` to a really large value. You can use the limits defined in `limits.h`

`int small = INT_MAX, large = INT_MIN;`

Answer (score 0):

Simple way, conceptually, would be to initialise `large` to `-Inf` and `small` to `+Inf`. Since you are using `int` values, just use values of biggest and smallest `int` from `limits.h`

```
#include <limits.h>
...
int n[5], i, small = INT_MAX, large = INT_MIN;
```